# Align span element to left of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible to align the span "Header" in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/25LjE/37/ to right of text as shown :

[image]

I'm creating the header using jquery.

Here is the fiddle code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6352993.js"></script>
<noscript><a href="http://polldaddy.com/poll/6352993/">This is very long test question to test how polldaddy handles questions that exceed that normal length............ yes a very long question indeed..............</a></noscript>

.pds-pd-link {
display: none !important;
}
.pds-box {
    width: 220px !important;
}
.pds-input-label{
    width: auto! important;
}
.PDS_Poll{
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.pds-question-inner').prepend('<center><span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;font-size: 10pt"><u>Header</u></span></center>');
});
```

When I try proposed solutions in IE8, the text is slightly higher than rest of text :

[image]

Can this be fixed ?

Comment: .prepend('<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;font-size: 10pt; float:right;"><u>Header</u></span>');

Comment: <div style="float: right;"><center><span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;font-size: 10pt"><u>Header</u></span></center></div>

Comment: Align header to the right or the left? on your picture it shows left and in your question description, you say right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add `float:left` in

`<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;font-size: 10pt;float:left"><u>Header</u></span>`

Check this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/25LjE/44/)

Answer (score 1):

It is not really clear to me what you are trying to achive, but adding this CSS seems to get this done:

```
center span{
    position:relative;
    top:30px;
    left:-70px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by wrapping your two elements both in a div which float left, then you can append instead of prepend the header.

```
<div class="floatLeft">Your two elements</div>

<style>
.floatLeft {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

You may want to set a width and padding/margin on the elements as well so they come out as desired.  If you want the header way to the right you can float it right instead of left. If you do that stick with the prepend because some versions of IE screw up floats if the right floating elements are not first in the series.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code at fiddle I have edited it http://jsfiddle.net/25LjE/46/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want?

```
$('.pds-question-inner').prepend('<center><span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;font-size: 10pt; text-align: right; display: block;"><u>Header</u></span></center>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/84fjB/

If not it should be, looks better :P

Answer (score 0):

You can add `float: left` to the span (and clean up your HTML).

You can check this: http://jsfiddle.net/ooflorent/zvbzT/